# Using Joomla within Wordpress

Tags: component, cms, wordpress

I use Wordpress for my site but I want to use a shopping cart extension that is designed for Joomla. I know there are other plugins for Wordpress but I have to use this Joomla extension.

- Does anyone know of a way of using Joomla within Wordpress?
- Can Joomla be used in a Wordpress template?
- Would it be best if having an iframe and load Joomla in that way?

I don't want to run them side by side and have to maintain two CMS systems.

Thank you

Comment: There are lots of ways but the easiest is probably to go look at the Joomla extensions directory to find an integration extension.

Comment: What is the name of the extension?

Comment: I would run Joomla alone, and avoid the hurdle of duplicated management on two CMSs.

Comment: Without knowing the ins and outs of your scenario I can already tell you its definitely a bad idea! You're better off using only Joomla and scrapping WordPress...

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=wordpress

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Joomla over WordPress, that said it doesn't answer your question.

You can't make one CMS run inside the other. They will have to be two separate systems, and you will need to create a template for Joomla to match WordPress.

**The way I would do it is as such:**

Have WP installed on your root, then create a sub folder - something like products or store in which to install Joomla 3.x.

So accessing your store would be by going to www.example.com/products

You will need to manually add links to each site and it will be harder to maintain. If you have PHP/MySQL experience on the Joomla template you could create a query to the WP database to get article information so you could have "latest news" or something in the side coloumn.

**Two side notes:**

1) Don't try and have users get confused. Either register them on Joomla, or WP. Trying to do both will make it messy (if you even what user registration that is)

2) If you do use Joomla, and use a decent backup software like Akeeba then also get it to backup your WP database.

Answer (score 0):

I would use only Joomla, but if you still want to run WP, you could integrate it inside your Joomla website, using one of the extensions that can be found here:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog-integration

If you are looking to integrate Joomla into WP, then you should look at WP plugins directory and not at Joomla's.